# How to display, center and zoom a map using OpenLayers?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, geoserver

I started learning the OpenLayers and GeoServer. The layer is added at GeoServer using the OSM shape file which is indicated as `EPSG:4326` with bounds `[68.5094575, 6.6791812, 97.0315678, 35.3123975]`. Using OpenLayers this layer is obtained as WMS and getting displayed.

For displaying the map the following line of code is used:

```js
map.getView().fit(bounds, map.getSize());
```

Now the map is getting displayed. But when I use the below code, the map is not getting displayed:

```js
map.getView().fit(bounds, map.getSize());
map.getView().setCenter(ol.proj.transform[77.216574, 28.627671], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'));
map.getView().setZoom(5);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `bounds`? Is it the array `[68.5094575, 6.6791812, 97.0315678, 35.3123975]`?

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error:

```
map.getView().setCenter(ol.proj.transform[77.216574, 28.627671], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'));
```

should be:

```
map.getView().setCenter(ol.proj.transform([77.216574, 28.627671], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'));
```

If I change that and remove the `map.getView().fit(bounds, map.getSize());`

The map works:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.map {
  height: 95%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v5.3.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>

<div id="map" class="map"></div>
<script>
  var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({ // TileLayer({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      })
    ],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View()
  });
  map.getView().setCenter(ol.proj.transform([77.216574, 28.627671], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'));
  map.getView().setZoom(5);
</script>
```